# How to create custom confirmation buttons

Tags: c#, botframework

We are trying to implement a field similar to Confirmation field, that allows *continuing/quitting* the form (instead of the regular confirmation field which only allows continuing/changing form fields).

We managed to make this work well, but the only thing missing is the ability to know which is the next field after the `quitForm` field.

When we call `NextStep()` the form quits instead of just moving to the next field like Confirmation is doing.

How can we mimic the behavior of Confirmation?

This is our implementation, its very similar to Confirmation.cs:

```
public class QuitFormField<T> : Field<T> where T : class
{
        private const string c_continueTerm = "Continue";
        private const string c_quitTerm = "Quit";

        public QuitFormField(
            string prompt,
            string nextField,
            ActiveDelegate<T> condition, 
            IEnumerable<string> dependencies) : base(name: Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), role:FieldRole.Confirm)
        {
            SetPrompt(new PromptAttribute(prompt));
            SetDefine((state, field) =>
            {
                field.AddDescription(value: c_continueTerm, description: c_continueTerm).AddTerms(value: c_continueTerm, terms: c_continueTerm);
                field.AddDescription(value: c_quitTerm, description: c_quitTerm).AddTerms(value: c_quitTerm, terms: c_quitTerm);
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            });

            SetType(null);
            SetDependencies(dependencies?.ToArray());
            SetActive(condition);
            _next = (value, state) => (string)value == c_continueTerm ? new NextStep(nextField) : new NextStep(StepDirection.Quit);

        }
}
```

Clarification: We wanted NextStep() to move to the next field without us having to specify the next field name

Comment: Are you working with the latest version of the framework?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work in my form.

Changes:

1. `new NextStep(nextField)` gives a compilation error. Changed to: `new NextStep(new []{nextField})`
2. Changed `_next = delegate` to `SetNext(delegate)`
3. I added some methods and properties overrides for the Field.

   ```
   private const string c_continueTerm = "Continue";
   private const string c_quitTerm = "Quit";

   public QuitFormField(
       string prompt,
       string nextField,
       ActiveDelegate<T> condition,
       IEnumerable<string> dependencies) : base(name: Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), role: FieldRole.Confirm)
   {
       SetPrompt(new PromptAttribute(prompt));
       SetDefine((state, field) =>
       {
           field.AddDescription(value: c_continueTerm, description: c_continueTerm).AddTerms(value: c_continueTerm, terms: c_continueTerm);
           field.AddDescription(value: c_quitTerm, description: c_quitTerm).AddTerms(value: c_quitTerm, terms: c_quitTerm);
           return Task.FromResult(true);
       });

       SetType(null);
       SetDependencies(dependencies?.ToArray());
       SetActive(condition);
       SetNext((value, state) => (string)value == c_continueTerm ? new NextStep(new []{nextField}) : new NextStep(StepDirection.Quit));
   }

   public override object GetValue(T state)
   {
       return null;
   }

   public override IEnumerable<string> Dependencies => _dependencies;

   public override bool Active(T state)
   {
       return _condition(state);
   }

   public override NextStep Next(object value, T state)
   {
       return _next((string)value, state);
   }

   public override void SetValue(T state, object value)
   {}

   public override bool IsUnknown(T state)
   {
       return true;
   }

   public override void SetUnknown(T state)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. We wanted NextStep() to move to the next field without us having to specify the next field name. Woud you know how to do that?